How to find LP tokens and Burning LP tokens? - Solana - Raydium
First question: Where or how to find LP tokens after adding liquidity on Raydium?
Added some liquidity to Car Coin on Raydium for testing purposes. First I added .59 sol, then .29 sol. The pool was created, but the LP tokens never showed up in the wallet.
I created the wallet using the windows command prompt and the Solana Token Program to create a Key-Pair, then imported the key into Phantom. The wallet works fine.
The open positions can be seen here:
solscan open position 1
solscan open position 2
Having trouble finding any documentation on raydium, all their docs say is that the RCL token will appear in the wallet. I tried to copy the address from solscan to import into the wallet, but they don't come up.
Second question: How to burn these LP tokens?
Solana seems to have written a paper on medium on how to do this here:
Medium article
Using this tool:
Burner tool
I tried to copy the RCL addresses from solscan and input into the burner, but nothing comes up.
